# Algorithm to find combination of n numbers with largest sum

Tags: algorithm, puzzle

Problem is simple - 
Suppose I have an array of following numbers - 
4,1,4,5,7,4,3,1,5
I have to find number of sets of k elements each that can be created from above numbers having largest sum. Two sets are considered to be different if they have at least one different element.
e.g.
if k = 2, then there can be two sets - {7,5} and {7,5}. Note: 5 appears twice in above array.

I think I can start with something like- 
1. Sort array
2. Create two arrays. One for different number and an other in parallel for number's occurence.

But I am stuck now. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm is as follows:

1) Sort elements in descending order.

2) Look at this array. It may look something like this:

```
   a ... a b ... b c ... c d ...
   |  <-    k   ->    |
```

Now obviously all elements `a` and `b` will be in the sets with the largest sum. You can't replace any of them with a smaller element, because then the sum wouldn't be the largest possible. So you have no choice here, you have to choose all `a` and `b` for *any* of the sets.

On the other hand only *some* of the elements `c` will be in those sets. So the answer is just the number of possibilities, to choose `c`'s to fill the positions left in the sets, after you have taken *all* larger elements. That is the binomial coefficient:

`count of c's` **choose** `(k - (count of elements larger than c))`

For example for an array (already sorted here)

```
[9, 8, 7, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

and `k = 6`, you **must** choose 9, 8 and both 7's for every set with the largest sum (which is 41). And then you can choose any *two* out of the *four* 5's. So the result will be `4 choose 2 = 6`.

With the same array and `k = 4`, the result would be `x choose 0 = 1` (that unique set is `{9, 8, 7, 7}`), with `k = 7` the result would be `4 choose 3 = 4`, and with `k = 9`: `2 choose 1 = 2` (choosing any 4 for the set with the largest sum).

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** I edited the answer, because we figured it out that OP needs to count multisets.

First, find the largest `k` numbers in the array. This is of course easy, and if `k` is very small, you can do it in `O(k)` by performing `k` linear scans. If `k` is not so small, you can use a binary heap, or a priority queue or just sort the array to do that which is respectively `O(n * log(k))` or `O(n * log(n))` when using sorting.

Let assume that you have computed `k` largest numbers. Of course all sets of size `k` with the largest sum have to contain exactly these `k` largest numbers and no more other numbers. On the other hand, any different set doesn't have the largest sum.

Let `count[i]` be the number of occurrences of number `i` in the input sequence.

Let `occ[i]` be the number of occurrences of number `i` in the largest `k` numbers.

We can compute these both tables in very different ways, for example using a hash table or if input numbers are small, you can use an array indexed by these numbers.

Let `B` be the array of **distinct** numbers from the largest `k` numbers.
Let `m` be the size of `B`.

Now let's compute the answer. We will do it in `m` steps. After `i`-th step we will have computed the number of different multisets consisting of the first `i` numbers from `B`. At the beginning the result is `1` since there is only one empty multiset. In the `i`-th step, we will multiply the current result by the number of possible chooses of `occ[B[i]]` elements from `count[B[i]]` elements, which is equal to `binomial(occ[i], count[i])`

For example, let's consider your instance with added one more 7 at the end and `k` set to 3:

> k = 3
>
> A = [4, 1, 4, 5, 7, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7]

The largest three numbers in `A` are `7, 7, 5`

At the beginning we have:

```
count[7] = 2
count[5] = 2
occ[7] = 2
occ[5] = 1
result = 1
B = [7, 5]
```

We start with the first element in B which is 7. Its `count` is 2 and its `occ` is also 2, so we do:

```
// binomial(2, 2) is 1
result = result * binomial(2, 2)
```

Next element in B is 5, its `count` is 2 and its `occ` is 1, so we do:

```
// binomial(2, 1) is 2
result = result * binomial(2, 1)
```

And the final result is 2, since there are two different multisets `[7, 7, 5]`

Comment: I think your logic would fail for k =3 because for k=3, there exists only one set - [7,5,5] ?

Comment: So you are asking for sets or multisets?

Comment: Not sure about the difference :P

Comment: A set is basically the bag of different elements. A multiset can have same elements.

Comment: and the order of elements in resulting sets matter or not?

Comment: Thanks pkacprzak for your time and solution.. :)

Comment: Re "find the largest k numbers in the array", the claim "you can do it in O(k) by performing k linear scans" is false.  Because each scan is O(n) doing k linear scans is O(kn)

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a sorted dictionary of the frequencies of occurrence of the numbers in the input. Then take the two largest numbers and multiply the number of times they occur.

In C++, it could look something like this:

```
std::vector<int> inputs { 4, 1, 4, 5, 7, 3, 1, 5};
std::map<int, int> counts;

for (auto i : inputs) 
    ++counts[i];

auto last = counts.rbegin();

int largest_count = *last;
int second_count = *++last;

int set_count = largeest_count * second_count;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1) Sort the elements in descending order;

2) define variable answer=1;

3) Start from the beginning of the array and for each new value you see, count the number of its occurrence (lets call this variable count). every time do: answer = answer * count. The pseudo-code should look like this.

```
find_count(Array A, K)
{
   sort(A,'descending);
   int answer=1;
   int count=1;
   for (int i=1,j=1; i<K && j<A.length;j++)
   {
        if(A[i] != A[i-1])
        {
            answer = answer *count;
            i++;
            count=1;
        }
        else
            count++;
   }
      return answer;
}
```